# Can I modify Jquery to use conditional statements based on which URL is returned?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I have a site which uses different page templates and calls jquery to stick the site header on scroll past a certain number of pixels. This sticky class works flawlessly on the page template with a fixed banner, but on the ones where I have not included a banner I would like to change the position at which the scroll function is called. For example, appearing at 250 rather than 500 pixels.

The script is on Wordpress site, built with `_s` and `sass` and is quoted below:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var sticky = $('.site-header'),
       scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

   if (scroll >= 500) sticky.addClass('sticky-header');

   else sticky.removeClass('sticky-header');    
});
```

The solutions two I can think of are a) Making a conditional statement to trigger different scroll positions based on URL selectors b) Creating a second header div class (`.site-header-2`) and an additional jquery document which affects only that class.

The second I can do, although it would be less elegant and time consuming if I were to create multiple page templates all with different fixed scroll heights.

Using the syntax in the script above, is there a simple solution to using a conditional argument, for varying fixed scroll positions based on page URL structure or another way of achieving this which I am unaware of?

Comment: Declare a variable when you add a banner and when that variable exists do condition a, else do condition b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for existence of your banner element and set scroll start point accordingly

```
// within document.ready
var isBannerPage = $('#bannerId').length;// adjust selector to fit actual
var scrollStart = isBannerPage ? 500 : 250;
//cache element outside event handler to avoid searching many times a second for same element
var sticky = $('.site-header');

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var  scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

   if (scroll >= scrollStart ) sticky.addClass('sticky-header');

   else sticky.removeClass('sticky-header');    
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Seems to work, also gives me a better understanding of what can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to solve this is either just using a conditional statement with different classes, something like

```
var threshold = 0;
if ( $(.site-header).length > 0 ) 
{
     threshold = 500;
}
else threshold = <something else>
```

But ideally, you shouldn't have to care about hardcoded values, like "500". You likely want to make the header sticky when the scrolltop passes by it, right?
In that case, you could set `threshold` dynamically, to something like `$('site-header').offset().top`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into implementing the dynamic solution as I think this would be good long term.

Comment: It is, and mostly it's easy, generally. Easier than manually checking sizes. I don't remember the details and differences, but jQuery offers both $(element).position() and $(element).offset(), which has positional data you can use.